# Why do the files that do not exist in the "problem" suggest a lot of errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This problem has been confusing me for a long time. These files are not in my project. I can't find them, but I will report a lot of errors. Maybe these are compiled cache files? So how do I eliminate these error tips?

[image]

These errors do not affect my project running and compiling, but it is always there and cannot be eliminated.